# Python Class with three functions

Tags: python

I have built a python class, which takes a string as input

I have put 3 functions in the python class.
First function is to count no of upper and lower case
Second function is to truncate the string
Third function is to check if the string is a palindrome

```
class stringUtility():

    def _init_(self,string):
        self.string = string
    
    def upperlower(self):
  
        upper = 0
        lower = 0
  
        for i in range(len(self.string)):
          
            # For lower letters
            if (ord(self.string[i]) >= 97 and ord(self.string[i]) <= 122):
                lower += 1
  
            # For upper letters
            elif (ord(self.string[i]) >= 65 and ord(self.string[i]) <= 90):
                upper += 1
  
        print('Lower case characters = %s' %lower,
            'Upper case characters = %s' %upper)

# # Driver Code
# string = 'jjfkhgbhf'
# #upperlower(string)

    def trimString(self):

        trimmedString = self.string[:10] + "..."

        if len(self.string) <= 10:
            print(self.string)

        else:
            print(trimmedString)

# string2 = "fdsfsdfsdfsdf"

# #trimString(string2)


    def checkPalindrome(self):

        reverseString = self.string[::-1]
        convert_to_palindrome = self.string + reverseString[1:]

        if reverseString == self.string:
            print('input is a palindrome')

        else:
            print(convert_to_palindrome )


    # string3 = 'dad'
    # checkPalindrome(string3)
  
person2 = stringUtility.upperlower('mayanDFSDDk')
```

But i am   getting the error:

```
 File "class.py", line 58, in <module>
    person2 = stringUtility.upperlower('mayanDFSDDk')
  File "class.py", line 11, in upperlower
    for i in range(len(self.string)):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'string'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be `person2 = stringUtility('mayanDFSDDk').upperlower()`

`stringUtility.upperlower('mayanDFSDDk')` calls `upperlower` directly with a string argument, not instance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an instance of your class to call member functions.

```
person2 = stringUtility('mayanDFSDDk').upperlower()
```

Answer (score 2):

To add on to other answers, should be `__init__` not `_init_`

Comment: is there a way i could call all three functions in the class with one command, instead of calling each function separately

Comment: You could just make one function which calls the other 3 functions. If you want to make this call upon object initialization, you can call this function in the constructur (`__init__`)